# Testing the exogeneity of the subsets of instruments

Tags: hypothesis-testing, causality, instrumental-variables

Suppose that there is one endogenous variable and three instruments. The aim is to test whether instrument_3 is an exogenous instrument. The relevant statistic is the C statistic which is also called the Difference-in-Hansen-Sargan statistic. Before I got to know about the C statistic, I used to test for the exogeneity of an instrument using a heuristic test. I call it heuristic because I do not know if it is a formal test. That is the question. The test I consider goes as follows. Consider the reduced for regression where the endogenous variable is instrumented by two instrumental variables. In the reduced form regression I include the third instrument directly next to the exogenous variables, and check if it is significant. If it is, the third instrument is not exogenous because then it directly affects the dependent. That is I consider the following regression

$dependent = \beta_{1} (endo\_var = ins\_1 \: ins\_2) + \beta_{2} ins_3 + \beta_{3} exo\_var + u$

and check if $\beta_{2}$ is significant. If it is significant, the third instrument is not exogenous.

I figure that the result of this heuristic test is always in line with the result of the C test. That is, if the third instrument is significant, then I fail to C test too. This is perhaps not surprising, but I wonder whether this heuristic test is indeed a heuristic test, or is it somewhat a formal test that people use?